# How can i show previous 30 days in my list calendar?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a calendar, that works correct but shows only current day and future. How can i set previous days? I'd like to highliht a current day but also give an opportunity to scroll it to right and left. Maybe have your already faced to this problem. Help me please.

This is a whole class, you can try it

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentDateSelectedIndex = 0; //For Horizontal Date
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now(); // TO tracking date
  late var selectedDateNew;
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(); //Scroll Controller for ListView
  List<String> listOfMonths = [
    "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"
  ];


  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 30));
    selectedDateNew = formatDate(selectedDate, [yyyy, '-', mm, '-', dd]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FixedExtentScrollController itemController = FixedExtentScrollController();
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: calendar_carousel(),
        )
    );
  }


  Widget calendar_carousel() {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
        child: ScrollSnapList(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemBuilder: _buildDaysList,
          allowAnotherDirection: true,
          itemSize: 196,
          initialIndex: 0, //i tryed to put here another number, i didn't work
          dynamicItemSize: true,
          selectedItemAnchor: SelectedItemAnchor.MIDDLE,
          onReachEnd: (){
            print('Done!');
          },
          itemCount: 365,
          onItemFocus: (int) {
            setState(() {
              scrollController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(days: int), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
              currentDateSelectedIndex = int;
              selectedDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: int));
              selectedDateNew = formatDate(selectedDate, [yyyy, '-', mm, '-', dd]);
              //fetch(selectedDateNew);
            });
          },
        )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDaysList(BuildContext context, int index){
    return Container(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 196,
        height: 80,
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index)).day.toString()),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(listOfMonths[DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: index)).month - 1].toString(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i used dependensies

- scroll_snap_list: ^0.8.6
- date_format: ^2.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using.

`var lastMonth = new DateTime(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);`

Comment: Hi!
Thanks you for answer. Where i should to use it?

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: It helped. I managed to open previos days. Thank you! =)